# Reload a fragment when from DatePickerFragment onDateSet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to refresh/reload a fragment after I set a different date.
So I have created a DatePickerFragment that extends DialogFragment and implements `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

Inside my onDataSet function I have this code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment reload = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mealsworkoutsfrag");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("newdate",date);
    ft.detach(reload);
    reload.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.attach(reload);
    ft.commit();
```

Now if I run this a get an error on the reload.setArgs line saying

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method '`void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setArguments(android.os.Bundle)`' on a null object reference"

By the way in my main activity i create my fragment like this:

```
FragmentTransaction mealsworkoutsFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mealsworkoutsFrag.replace(R.id.flMain,new MealsWorkoutsFragment(),"mealsworkoutsfrag");
        mealsworkoutsFrag.commit();
```

What am I missing?

Edit: Extra code requested

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.mealworkoutTab) {
        iconShow = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        FragmentTransaction mealsworkoutsFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mealsworkoutsFrag.replace(R.id.flMain,new MealsWorkoutsFragment(),"mealsworkoutsfrag");
        mealsworkoutsFrag.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.userinfoTab) {
        iconShow = false;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        FragmentTransaction userInfoFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        userInfoFrag.replace(R.id.flMain,new UserInfoFragment(),"userinfofrag");
        userInfoFrag.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.logoutTab) {
        auth.signOut();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And here is the datepicker:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    final String d,m,y,date;

    month = month +1;

    if (String.valueOf(day).length() == 1) {
        d = "0"+day;
    }
    else {
        d = String.valueOf(day);
    }

    if (String.valueOf(month).length() == 1) {
        m = "0"+month;
    }
    else {
        m = String.valueOf(month);
    }

    y = String.valueOf(year);

    date = d+m+y;
    //EventBus.getDefault().post(new DateEvent(date));
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment reload = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mealsworkoutsfrag");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("newdate",date);
    ft.detach(reload);
    reload.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.attach(reload);
    ft.commit();

}
```

}

Here is how i call the date picker:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.date_picker) {

        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more code?

You could have many mistakes in all the logic you are using. For example, which class your activities and fragments extends, imports, etc.

I guess maybe using getActivity().getFragmentManager(); in the onDateSet works.

Another solution is to add a listener implementation in the Fragment and call it from onDateSet. (Communication between fragments).

Comment: The fragments and the dialogfragment are called from my main activity which extends AppCompatActivity andimplements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener .

Comment: Ok, so do you have a DialogFragment and MealsWorkoutsFragment that are called from the activity, right? In that case you can use the listener that I told about communication or maybe the getFragmentManager are you using is not the correct.
Are the imports from app4, right?

Comment: Yep v4. For now im trying to find why getFragmentManager is not correct

Comment: Yes, try to debug at the point of onDateSet and looks what do you have in the fragmentManager, fragmentManager.getFragments() and check if there is a fragment there.